# Shorten filter and map in Kotlin

Tags: filter, kotlin, mapping

From a list of nullable `Transformation` objects that contain a user I want the non-null IDs of non-null users. Is there a way to shorten this expression?

```
val list: List<Transformation> = ...
list.filter {t -> t.user!!.id !== null }.map { t -> t.user!!.id!! }
```

Comment: Not a list of nullable users, as you say, but some kind of wrapper elements

Comment: What is the user property of your User class??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `mapNotNull`:

```
list.mapNotNull { t -> t.user?.id }
```

This will filter out all `null` users from list and also IDs (of non-null users) which are `null`.

Note that your usage of `!!` is not correct in this case. it will cause `NullPointerException`s for `null`s in your list. You should have a look at how the nullability operators work in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: First, thanks for the quick answer, that's much better than before! Second, in that particular list, I am sure that the user, although it's generally nullable, is never null in that particular case. Of course, it might throw a NPE, but it might throw any other Exception, as well, since that case must never occur regarding the business logic.

Comment: Same here! The `!!` always seems like the poor man's way. Possibly the clean way would be to convert everything into another object with a non-null user, which actually would be very verbose if it's just about a single property whose `non-nullness` toggles. What do you think?

Comment: I wouldn't put it quite this way. IMHO `!!` is for when you, the developer, can be sure that a value is not null, but the compiler cannot. Of course, there are increasingly better ways to guarantee this (e.g. contracts in 1.3+)

Answer (score 2):

From your example code, it's not clear what's in the list. It does not seam to be a list of users, but a list of something, containing a user.

Given that

```
class User(val id: Int)

fun getIds(userList: List<User?>): List<Int> {
    return userList.filterNotNull().map { it.id }
}
```

or as an extension function:

```
fun List<User?>.getIds2() = filterNotNull().map { User::id }
```

Comment: Sorry, I've skipped the declaration of the list, but it is actually a `List<User>`, implicitly inferred by Kotlin. I'm gonna add it to the post.

Comment: @Matt So the User class has a property named `user`? That's quite confusing.

Comment: Oh boy, it's too early. You're right, it's a list of `Transformation`s that contain a user. Thanks for the hint.